# Generate signed apk in multiple pc

Tags: android

I am trying to generate signed apk for the same app in two different pc. One signed apk will be used to update. I am using the same keystore file. But when I update the app, it says "App not installed".

Answer (score 0):

have you tried increase the version in `build.gradle` file?

```
versionCode 2
versionName "1.1"
```